# Problem with Texstudio in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: miktex, texlive, texstudio, texmaker, ubuntu

I am new to Ubuntu (I have Ubuntu 18.04) and I have tried to install Texstudio for three days, but I have always had problems. I have tried EVERYTHING what I found on the Internet, but NOTHINGS works. I feel really hopeless. Can you help me to remove everything related to LaTeX (because I am not sure that I uninstall everything - Texmaker, Texstudio, Texlive and Miktex) and to install Texstudio, please? I know how to use terminal.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please describe the problem that you're encountering?  It should just be sudo apt install texlive-full

Comment: Hi, I tried to write "udo apt install texlive-full ", but it was not enought. :(  There was written, that I have to install Miktex or Texlive, but I had had to install Miktex few minutes before. I tried to uninstall everithing and to install again, but it did not help.

Comment: Tex studio is simply one text editor that writes the .TeX files, once written you need a TeX engine to do the compiling from text to image/pdf thus the FIRST task is install Tex Live (a multi GB download) or use a basic MiKTeX that will keep expanding as you work BUT needs more maintenance you need to decide and install the simplest for you

Comment: I tried to write for example: 
$ sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra and then I wrote 
$ sudo apt install texstudio (see https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-latex-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)
What did I do wrong?

Comment: I just want to add that I installed Texstudio on Windows 7 and I had no problem, so I have problem only with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete all TeXLive and TeXStudio which you have installed so far with

```
sudo apt remove texlive-full
sudo apt remove texstudio
```

Then run in a terminal:

```
wget https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu/raw/master/install-tl-ubuntu
```

then

```
chmod +x ./install-tl-ubuntu
```

then

```
sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu
```

this will take some time ... After that

```
sudo apt install texstudio
```

Now you can start TeXstudio from the menu. You can update your TeX distribution by running

```
sudo tlmgr --self --all update
```

If you want get rid of the sudo then run

```
sudo chown -R <USER> /usr/local/texlive
```

Then you can run all as user which simplifies some things.

Comment: I did everything, but there is written:
Make sure that you have installed a (La)TeX distribution e.g. MiKTeX or TeX Live, and have set the correct paths to this distribution on the command configuration page.
A (La)TeX editor like TeXstudio cannot work without the (La)TeX commands provided by such a distribution.

Comment: Did you restart Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it did not help. :(

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` say?

Comment: /opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: looks good. Does `ls -l /opt/` shows `texbin->/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux`  ??

Comment: Yes. 
$ ls -l /opt/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 jan 28 19:38 google
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   40 jan 29 20:01 texbin -> /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux

Comment: also fine! If texstudio now did not find the TeXLive binaries, which can be testet by running texstudio and then Options->Configure->Commands.  If the fields are _all_ empty then remove texstudio from Ubunto and run again `sudo apt install texstudio`.  Then the commands should be find by a next run of texstudio.

Comment: But they are not empty. What should I do?

Comment: that's fine!! For example my entry for `luaLaTeX` looks like `lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` Is it similiar to yours?

Comment: My luaLaTex is:
lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Comment: LateX: "/media/janka/E587-BFD2/K-Ubuntu/texstudio_2.12.14-1+2.1_amd64.deb" -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
PdfLaTeX: "/media/janka/E587-BFD2/K-Ubuntu/texstudio_2.12.14-1+2.1_amd64.deb" -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
XeLaTeX: xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
LuaLaTeX: lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
DVI Viewer: xdg-open %.dvi > /dev/null
PS Viewer: xdg-open %.ps > /dev/null
External PDF Viewer: xdg-open %.pdf > /dev/null
DviPs dvips -o %.ps %.dvi
Ps2Pdf: ps2pdf %.ps
DviPdf: dvipdfmx %.dvi
BibTex: bibtex %.aux
BibTex 8-Bit:bibtex8 %.aux

Comment: Biber: biber %
Makeindex: makeindex %.idx
Texindy: texindy %.idx
Makeglossaries: makeglossaries %
Metapost: mpost -interaction=nonstopmode ?me)
Asymptote: asy ?m*.asy
Ghostscript: gs "?am.ps"
Latexmk: latexmk -pdf -silent -synctex=1 %
SVN: <unknown>
SVNADMIN: <unknown>

Comment: can be last two problem?

Comment: For `latex` and `pdflatex` they are wrong. Replace it with `latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`  and `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`  Then _all_  should work!

Comment: by the way: You can update your TeX distribution by running `sudo tlmgr --self --all update`.  If you want get rid of the `sudo` then run `sudo chown -R <USER> /usr/local/texlive`.  Then you can run all as user which simplifies some things.

Comment: I am a little bit afraid to update something (after 4 days of trying to fix it), because I really need LaTeX now. :D But I will try it later. ;) 
Thank you for your help. You save my life and my bachelor thesis. Thanks!.